# Moving second input next to first

Tags: html

I need to move second input next to first input. If its possible, then its good when I need to change only HTML.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <input type="text" size="put_a_size_here" name="s" id="s" value="Otsing..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/> 
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Otsi" class="btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what I have at the moment

[image]

But I want this "Otsi" button next to search bar. I tried to do this with one input, but this didnt work

Added CSS

```
element {
}
.uneditable-input, input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], textarea {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}
.uneditable-input, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], input[type="search"], select, textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #555;
    border-radius: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.uneditable-input, input, textarea {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.uneditable-input, input, textarea {
    width: 80%;
}
.uneditable-input, input, textarea {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
button, input, label, select, textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
body, .navbar .nav > li > a {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
body, .navbar .nav > li > a {
    font-family: "Cantarell";
    font-weight: 400;
}
body {
    color: #5A5A5A;
}
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `.uneditable-input, input, textarea {  width: 80%; }` - this causes the problem

Comment: Thanks ! U can add this to answers and I can accept this ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should stack already, maybe your CSS is breaking it.

Here is my jsfiddle which should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ehtstdb/

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<div style="float:right;display: inline-block;">
        <input type="text" size="put_a_size_here" name="s" id="s"placeholder="Otsing..." /> 
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Otsi" class="btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

i also added placeholder text so you dont have to use that JS to remove the text when it gains focus.

Comment: Hmm, its wierd. But is there any way to force it? Because I really need this button next to search bar. I tried your code and this is not working either. In jsfiddle working my code perfectly too, but in wordpress... no

Comment: Hi, i have just put the code into chrome and it works great, i believe it is your styling that is breaking it. Can you post your CSS for me?

Comment: Its hard to find this CSS. Im using wordpress, and this search code is in theme header.php file. But this css what includes this header... I dont know where it is :D There is style.css, but this file is empty

Comment: Ah, well if you use inspect element you can highlight the CSS, it is your CSS that is breaking it so until you can provide that i can't help you any further sorry!

Comment: `display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #555;
    border-radius: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

Comment: Something block this there ?

Comment: Nothing there seems to be a problem. It has to be other parts of CSS doing it. Would you mind linking me to the wordpress site so i can see?

Comment: At the moment Im using localhost.. :(

Comment: Maybe put it on a free web host like 000webhost.com and then i can help you further.

Comment: I added CSS in to my question. But some lines are crossed if I inspect element

Comment: Lines that are crossed mean they are either incorrect or something is overriding them.

Comment: Okayy, and problem is probably in these lines ?

Comment: I should be able to inspect element it all and fix it for you

Comment: Okayy, but this takes time to put this up

Comment: Thanks for help, But Gene R found a solution now ;)

Comment: No problem, i didn't see the new CSS when i looked at your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing the attribute "display : inline -block " in the inputs. I Really do not know why you have this problem I use chrome and I see both winged one another. But it depends on the browser . I think by default inputs are inline but maybe your browser takes them as block. 
Ej of what im traying to say :

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<div style="float:right;">
    <input style="display:inline-block" type="text" size="put_a_size_here" name="s" id="s" value="Otsing..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/> 
    <input style="display:inline-block" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Otsi" class="btn"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your code and still same problem. And Im using Chrome ;)

Comment: So... I think the problem is that you have a container ( div or some other ) which has a very small width and don't let the inputs positioned one besides another. I hope you find the solution!